# Trying to parse a json array with swiftJson

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I am downloading a file which does just fine. I am then trying to parse this json to get a value out from it. This is where the error occurs. The file downloads fine I think. Here is what I have so far

```
 func parseYoutubeVideo(json : String)
{

    if let data = json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    {
        let newJson = JSON(data: data)
        //Get the youtube video from the Json data
        print("Parsing Video")
        self.myVideo = newJson["video"].stringValue
        //load the video
        print("Video parsed: " + self.myVideo)
        self.myYoutubePlayer .loadWithVideoId(myVideo)



    }
}
//Function to log into the server and retrive data
func  downloadVideoUrl(myUrl : String)
{
    print("Downloading video")
    Alamofire.request(.GET, myUrl)
        .authenticate(user: "admin", password: "admin")
        .validate()
        .responseString { response in
            print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
            print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")

            if(response.result.isSuccess == true)
            {
                self.parseYoutubeVideo(response.result.value!)
                //self.parseYoutubeVideo(self.testConfigJson)

            }else
            {
                //remove player from the view
                 self.myYoutubePlayer.removeFromSuperview()
            }



    }
}
```

This is what alamofire give me

```
Success: true
Response String: Optional("[ {\n  \"video\" : \"zKevpV_Qo7A\"\n} ]")
```

Is there something I am missing on how to do this or am i doing this completely wrong.
This is how you parse out a json array right?

Thank you for any help with this

Comment: What is your JSON? I could help you if you pasted the JSON response.

Comment: This is what it should give me [
  {
    "video": "zKevpV_Qo7A"
  }
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
let data = response.result.value!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
var json: NSArray?

do {
json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSArray
}
catch error as NSError {
print(error)
}
let video = (json[0] as! NSDictionary)["video"] as String
```

Comment: Thank you it took a bit or wrestling to get it to work properly but now my video is playing off the downloaded video, thank you a lot I appreciate it